# SELECT query on timestamp column, returning in GMT and not in the set timezone

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, mariadb

I have changed the mariadb config file, and restarted the mariadb to set the time zone to '+5:30'

And my current time zone is '+5:30' as confirmed by this query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone';
```

When selecting NOW(), it is returning correct time to me, as confirmed by

```
Select NOW();
```

I have a column "created_on" whose datatype is datetime, in a table which I am setting in the insert trigger. I am setting it to NOW() in the insert trigger.

```
SET NEW.created_on = NOW();
```

When I am selecting the "created_on" with a select query, it is showing me date time in the GMT, and not the timezone which I have set.

Please tell me what is the problem? and how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DATETIME` type columns are not adjusted according to timezone, whereas `TIMESTAMP` type columns are.

Comment: See documentation: `MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time.`. More information in: [11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';` -- and study their meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments by @eggyal and @wchiquito the answer is,

If you want to see the correct time in the select query then the datatype of the column should be timestamp and not datetime. 
Timestamp takes care of timezone when rendering in the select query.

Thanks @eggyal and @wchiquito